# How to get a sum of an array in Nodejs using foreach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, schema

I have an array/schema called "plants",and populating on a webpage. I want to get the sum of plant rates(last item). how can i do that in Nodejs?

Below is the template showing plants table with the data from schema:

```
<% project.plants.forEach(function(plant){ %>
                  <tr>

                     <td class="td14" ><%= plant.noplant %></td>
                     <td class="td15" ><%= plant.plantname %></td>
                     <td class="td16" ><%= plant.planthrperday %></td>
                     <td class="td17" ><%= plant.plantnodays %></td>
                     <td class="td18" ><%= plant.planthrrate %></td>
                     <td class="td19" ><%= plant.plantdep %></td>
                     <td class="td20" ><%= plant.plantrate %></td>
                     <td class="td21"><a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></a></td>

                   </tr>
                <% }); %>
```

The route handler:

```
    app.get("/myprojects/:id/cost", function(req,res){

    Project.findById(req.params.id).populate("labours materials tools plants others").exec(function(err, foundProject){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            }else{
          res.render("cost", {project: foundProject});   
        }

    });

  });
```

Comment: let sum = 0;
project.plants.forEach(function(plant){
sum = sum + plant.plantrate
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in template as I did below by declaring a variable `plantRateSum` and adding `plantrate` to that variable on every iteration of `forEach`

```
<% var plantRateSum = 0;  %>

<% project.plants.forEach(function(plant){ %>
          <% plantRateSum += plant.plantrate %> 
           enter code here
                  <tr>

                     <td class="td14" ><%= plant.noplant %></td>
                     <td class="td15" ><%= plant.plantname %></td>
                     <td class="td16" ><%= plant.planthrperday %></td>
                     <td class="td17" ><%= plant.plantnodays %></td>
                     <td class="td18" ><%= plant.planthrrate %></td>
                     <td class="td19" ><%= plant.plantdep %></td>
                     <td class="td20" ><%= plant.plantrate %></td>
                     <td class="td21"><a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></a></td>

                   </tr>
                <% }); %>
```

But this would not be a good approach instead you should send sum of plant rates to template from route handler using `reduce` method like below:

```
const plantRateSum = project.plants.reduce(function(sum, plant){
  return sum + plant.plantrate;
}, 0);
```

Now pass this `plantRateSum` to template.

In your route handler do this:

```
 app.get("/myprojects/:id/cost", function(req,res){
    Project.findById(req.params.id).populate("labours materials tools plants others").exec(function(err, foundProject){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        var plantRateSum = foundProject.plants.reduce(function(sum, plant){
          return sum + plant.plantrate;
        }, 0); 
        res.render("cost", {project: foundProject, plantRateSum:plantRateSum});   
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: the route handler is a bit complicated, I don't know how to add it:app.get("/myprojects/:id/cost", function(req,res){
 
 Project.findById(req.params.id).populate("labours materials tools plants others").exec(function(err, foundProject){
  if(err){
   console.log(err);
   }else{
    res.render("cost", {project: foundProject});  
  }
  
 });
 
  });

Comment: @Sam Please add the route handler to your question as in comment it would difficult to read it :)

Comment: sorry, i added to the question

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` as follows:

```
const plantsRateSum = project.plants.reduce((accumulator, currValue) =>{
  return acumulator + currValue.plantrate;
}, 0);
```

[Docs: Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Or in your particular case, calculate the sum after getting the plants array:

```
Project.findById(req.params.id).populate("labours materials tools plants others").exec(function (err, foundProject) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    const plantsRateSum = foundProject.reduce((accumulator, currValue) => {
      return acumulator + currValue.plantrate;
    }, 0);
    res.render("cost", { project: foundProject, plantsRateSum: plantsRateSum });
  }
});
```